# Rotating image via javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to rotate a image using javascript and it should be simple but I can't figure how to draw the image rotated at specific coordinate on the canvas.
Here's the code I found and am trying to use:

```
ctx.save();  
    // Translate to the center point of our image  
    ctx.translate(selectedImg.width * 0.5, selectedImg.height * 0.5);  
    // Perform the rotation  
    ctx.rotate( rotAngle * 0.01745 );  
    // Translate back to the top left of our image  
    ctx.translate(-selectedImg.width * 0.5, -selectedImg.height * 0.5);  
    // Finally we draw the image  
    ctx.drawImage(selectedImg, 0, 0);  
    // And restore the context ready for the next loop  
    ctx.restore();
```

it just rotates the image on top-left corner. how can I draw the image to let's say bottom-right?

Comment: The '0, 0" in `ctx.drawImage(selectedImg, 0, 0);` appears to be the coordinates.

Comment: yeah but I have tried different values there but it just makes the image fly around

Comment: Why should the image "fly around"? Animated? Is this all of your relevant code?

Comment: idk the rotation isn't working like expected. that's all draw code I have

Answer (score 0):

As it is documented on [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).
The function drawImage has three signatures.

```
void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy);
void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
void ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
```

Where d stands for destination and s stands for source.

The solution here should be calculating the image resolution and canvas resolution and make sure to feet the image inside the canvas, then calculate the x,y axes where we should to draw the image.

```
ctx.save();
// Translate to the center point of our image  
ctx.translate(selectedImg.width * 0.5, selectedImg.height * 0.5);
// Perform the rotation  
ctx.rotate(rotAngle * 0.01745);
// Translate back to the top left of our image  
ctx.translate(-selectedImg.width * 0.5, -selectedImg.height * 0.5);
// Finally we calculate the destination and draw the image 

var selectedImgWidth  = selectedImg.width;
var selectedImgHeight = selectedImg.height;

var xOffset = selectedImgWidth < canvas.width ? (canvas.width - selectedImgWidth) : 0;
var yOffset = selectedImgHeight < canvas.height ? (canvas.height - selectedImgHeight) : 0;

ctx.drawImage(selectedImg, xOffset, yOffset);

// instead of ctx.drawImage(selectedImg, 0, 0);  
// And restore the context ready for the next loop  
ctx.restore();
```

I hope that resolve your issue.

Edit 1: Chenged destination target

Comment: Tested that code but it draws the image larger and still doesn't stay still

Comment: Do you want to keep the size of the image ?

Comment: still not working, the image flies around the canvas

Comment: I think I have figured out a solution, we need to do some math cos and sin to get the right height and wight after the image rotated

Comment: from what I understand technically it's the canvas that is rotated not the image

Answer (score 0):

This function works for me:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImageRotated = function (img,x,y,angle)
{

this.save();  


var cposX = x + img.width / 2;
var cposY = y + img.height / 2;



this.translate(cposX,cposY); // move canvas center

this.rotate(degToRad(angle));

this.translate(-cposX,-cposY);


this.drawImage(img, x, y);


this.restore();
    
}
```